# Mouse click event used gis application with much data

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers, feature-layer

I will create an application that using my water pipes, electric cables, gas pipes service in a city. All of streets and roads including water pipes. My service is publishing pipes. My service like following.

Pipe Service

- domain.com/arcgis/rest/services/Water/MapServer
- domain.com/arcgis/rest/services/Electric/MapServer
- domain.com/arcgis/rest/services/Gas/MapServer

Feature Layers

- Pipe Lines (Polyline): domain.com/arcgis/rest/services/Water/MapServer/0
- Water Valves (Point): domain.com/arcgis/rest/services/Water/MapServer/1

I wanna show pipes on map and users can click on pipes and get features about pipe. Which way can be make sense for this solution?
I think use FeatureLayers on map and on click method. How does it affect the performance. If I use ArcgisDynamicMapServiceLayer, I can not click pipes.

Comment: You can use a map service but you will have to get the feature info with something like a [QueryTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/querytask.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think the attribute inspector dijit, is what you're searching for.

I suggest looking at the [Using the attribute inspector](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/ed_attribute_inspector.html) page, all the code you need should be there.